# Peak detection/removal for mean colour values in image

Tags: python, numpy, pdf, matplotlib, image-processing

I'm wanting to process PDF files of previous exam questions into images which I can print out. I'm running into trouble when removing the lines (for writing on) and more useless whitespace. Here is an example of the page I'm trying to condense down.
[Example raw page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xFIr.png)

So, I first convert the PDF page to a PIL Image then convert that to a Numpy array.

My initial approach to removing the lines was to iterate over each row of pixels and calculate the mean colour value: the lower the value, the darker the line so the greater chance it would contain useful writing and not whitespace. I used matplotlib to visualise this. [It looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToXe2.png) (done for the same page as the above example).

You can clearly see the peaks in the ranges [160, 280] and [450, 750] where the very sharp peaks occur with no noise surrounding them whatsoever.

So I then decided to do 2 passes through the array, each calculating the mean colour value as it goes through. The first pass roughly removes the lines (the rows which have a rounded mean of 197). The second pass removed the rows which have a rounded mean above 254 (the whitespace). The resulting Numpy array is re-converted to a PIL image and then saved. It usually looks something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPPO5.png).

This is great for my purposes; however, this method fails when I try and feed it different PDF files which have lines peak at different mean values (although they still peak very sharply with no noise surrounding them).

How would I write a more general algorithm that can detect these sharp peaks and remove them without risking removing the real content of the question?

Comment: Something which I see from that visualization is that the lines are tiny sections of the plot, and whitespace is large swaths of the plot. One way which I could envision removing these is checking for comparing rows to the rows next to them using `np.diff`. If there is a tiny amount of consecutive rows which have the same value as each other (or a np.diff value = 0), it's a line, remove it. If there is a large amount of consecutive rows which have the same value as each other, it's whitespace.

Comment: Thanks - I hacked together a little implementation of what you described and it works great!